# Waiting takePicture ends

Tags: android, camera

Suppose the following piece of pseudocode

```
my_camera.takePicture(...)
Waiting call back ends
my_camera.release()
Manipulate picture
```

I have no idea on how to implement the line "waiting call back and" which waits that the picture is taken. So I thought to implement it as follows. In the call back:

```
PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback(){
 @Override
 public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
   Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length);
   picture_taken = true;
 }};
```

Then the above pseudocode becomes:

```
picture_taken = false;
my_camera.takePicture(...)
while (!picture_taken) ;
my_camera.release()
Manipulate picture
```

Is it correct proceed in this way?

Comment: Any reason you can't use the default camera to take the picture for you (using startActivityForResult) and then grab the resulting URI to load the bitmap and manipulate it (in onActivityResult)?

Comment: I do not want take a picture, save it, then reload it and manipulate it. I want take a picture and manipulate directly the data without the need of saving and load. In all the example I've found, people use to manipulate the image directly into the call back but I would like to take separate the call back with the image processing.

Comment: The question is not clear. Yes, the latest pseudo-code looks fine (except that different parts should take part in different threads) and it possible to implement using Camera.PictureCallback or Camera.PreviewCallback if You don't want to launch Camera app. But is there any particular programming problem? I cannot see any in the question, so vote for close.